# PyQt sort indicators are not completely visible

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qheaderview

I am working with PyQt5. I want to show a sort indicator for my QTableWidget, so I did:

```
table = QTableWidget()
table.setSortingEnabled(True)
table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
```

I prefer if the sort indicator was on the right of the table header so I added this

```
table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::down-arrow { subcontrol-position: center right}')
```

The problem is that when the indicator is on the right it is pretty much not visible. see below, on the left there is no arrow and on the right the arrow is pointing down.

[image: No arrow] [image: arrow pointing down]

If I add right: 10px to the stylesheet

```
table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::down-arrow { subcontrol-position: center right; right: 10px }')
```

I get this

[image: 10px to the right]

When the arrow is on top I find it too small

[image: top arrow up] [image: top arrow down]

Would anyone know how to make the sort indicator more visible (preferably on the right side)?

Working code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, \
QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))

        table = QTableWidget()
        table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::down-arrow { subcontrol-position: center right}')
        table.setColumnCount(4)
        table.setRowCount(4)

        # Set table headers
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Header-1", "Header-2", "Header-3", "Header-4"])

        # generate values
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(i) + ", " + str(j)))

        # display table
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(table)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.show()

# Create app object and execute app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = Window()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Try adding `right: 10px;` (note, properties must always end with a semicolon).

Comment: @musicamante I did setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::down-arrow { subcontrol-position: center right; right: 10px }') it shifted to the left but it's still just a couple of pixles. I added a screenshot in to the post

Comment: Uhm, seems like a bug. Are you using font scaling?

Comment: @musicamante no, does it work properly for you?